# Python Mechanize.Browser.Open(url) Status Code

Tags: python, screen-scraping, web-scraping, mechanize, mechanize-python

I recently moved from perl to python and am updating some of my scripts which used perls WWW::Mechanize to use python mechanize module.

All good so far but I cant get find the HTTP Status code anywhere? (200, 301, etc)

I've googled and found this but isnt their a way to just view the code?

[Getting and trapping HTTP response using Mechanize in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673022/getting-and-trapping-http-response-using-mechanize-in-python)

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `response.code`

```
from mechanize import Browser
browser = Browser()
response = browser.open('http://www.google.com')
print response.code
```

Comment: lol fail. Thanks! I used both ipython and eclipse pydev auto complete on the object and neither game me the option for .code. I've looked for a complete resource of all mechanize funtions with some description or example do you know of one? Thanks again!

Comment: I have actually used the `code` property before for some of my projects, but it does not show up when I call `dir(response)`. Good topic for another question though.